# Translating words using object

Tags: php, object, translation

I just want to translate some words. That's I think I will use object to translating like Javascript

In javascript I can do like

```
var data = {"one":"en","two":"to"};
console.log(data["one"]);
```

But in PHP why I can't do like..

```
$text = (object)array(
                "one"=>"en",
                "two"=>"to"
            );
echo $text["one"];
```

????

Or another idea ?

Comment: why the (object)? you are accessing it as an array not an object

Comment: ok ok :D , in JS to using obj is so simple to translating data. Now i know in PHP just use only array :D @cernunnos

Comment: In JS you can access an object as if it was an array, if JS did not offer this "freedom" the only way to access an objects property would be: object.property. The equivalent in php would be $object->property (assuming you can access it). Doing name[index] is an array access in many if not most languages :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply drop the `(object)` cast, because in PHP, arrays work as you want to:

```
$text = array('one' => 'en', 'two' => 'to');

echo $text['one'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `echo $text->one;` if its a json decoded array for accessing standard class object array using `->` operator